# How do I convert Protocol Relative URLs to standard HTTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, wkhtmltoimage

I'm working with the [wkhtmltoimage](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) utility which does not support protocol relative URLs such as this: `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>`

I need to convert it to: `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>` in Ruby. I'm wondering what the most efficient way of finding these type of URLs as I can't figure out how to write a regex for them and then prepend `http:` to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use perl for that :

```
perl -pi -e 's/src="\/\//src="http:\/\//' *
```

This statement above will replace all patterns found in a directory.

Comment: Thanks. Should have realised it would be easy.

Comment: This will break if there is any text containing the string `src="//…` anywhere outside of a `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `Regexp`s here, just use an HTML parser for the HTML and a URI parser for the URI:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(<<-EOHTML)
  <script 
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js">
  </script>
EOHTML

doc.xpath('//script[@src]').each do |script|
  uri = URI.parse(script['src'])  
  uri.scheme = 'http' if uri.scheme.nil?  
  script['src'] = uri.to_s
end
```